# Path.isconvex is not supported. Rendering issue in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

I am creating an android app and
I added some toggle buttons,  edittext and I am also adding fragments in it dynamically. 
But when previewing the layout in Android studio, it shows this warning:

> The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate :
>        - Path.isconvex is not supported.

Answer (score 8):

If you have round corners somewhere like this

```
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"/>
```

try replacing it with:

```
<corners android:radius="10dp" />
```

Currently seems corners with different radius is not supported.